# Clipping a circle with svg... or?

Tags: svg

[image]

Currently I am using canvas to draw the gold circle, then snip off the areas half way to adjacent stars with `globalCompositeOperation : destination-out`, then paste the result into the main canvas.

I am contemplating changing to svg for this.
The closest method I have found is clip masks. I would have to create a set of clip-masks for each circle (star), this seems excessive if there were 2000 stars.

Another way would be to create polygons, but the math required to calculate the path may be beyond my capabilities.

So before I go down either of these routes, I would like to know if there is a better way or which of the above methods are recommended.

Comment: What you do looks a lot like a Voronoi diagram. [tag:d3.js] has a [module](https://github.com/d3/d3-delaunay/) for that.

Comment: Good to know Voronoi is what I am doing, Thanks! Looking for a way to do it with svg